# Laplace-Beltrami operator on complex projective space.

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-space

Where I can find a proof of the formula for Laplace-Beltrami operator for the Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb{CP}^{n}$?

I've found this formula on page 8 in this work: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.06470v2.pdf .

Title of this work: ,,Stochastic areas, Winding numbers and Hopf fibrations".

Please help me with my problem.

Comment: I don't know, but I would start by checking these: Griffiths and Harris, Principles of Algebraic Geometry; Huybrechts, Complex Geometry; Wells, Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds.

Comment: Thank You for Your help.